# Find the values $\omega_{X}(v)$ of the $1$-forms of $\omega$ at all possible locations $X$ and directions $V$

Tags: derivatives, differential-geometry, differential-forms

I just started reading from a differential forms book, and I've been struggling with the following problem:

> Find the values $\omega_{X}(v)$ of the $1$-forms of $\omega$ at all
>   possible locations $X$ and directions $V$ for
>
> $$\omega = (y^2 - x^2)\mathop{dx} + y^2 \mathop{dy} + z\mathop{dx} + y
>  \mathop{dy} - xy^{2} \mathop{dz}$$
>
> for $X = (2,3),(3,5),(1,-1),(2,3,4)$ and $V = (3,-7,1),(4,5),(-2,1)$.

I really have no idea how to stat this problem, and the book doesn't have many examples similar to it. I was wondering if someone could please explain the answer to me in a slow way for someone new to this type of thing.

Comment: So $\omega$ is a $1$-form on $\mathbb{R}^3$.  But you have points $x$ given in both $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{R}^3$.  Similarly for your tangent vector $V$.  If everything is given on the same manifold (e.g., $\mathbb{R}^3$), it would be simple enough, but without that what you have makes no sense.

Comment: This is all of the information I was given. I just rechecked and I typed the problem correctly. The problem is ranked as 'Easy' though so I don't think it's super complicated

Comment: I don't know if it helps, but I think I'm supposed to match the $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ and $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ points to the $1$ form that fits it